# Create ghost character from a certain point in cloth simulation

Tags: cloth-simulation

newbie here, so please be kind.  I tried googling and searching here for an answer but I think I just don't know correct terms to use.

I am trying to model a ghost for a game.  I have a frame (UV sphere extruded down) and a plane with cloth modifier that I drape over it.  When I run the cloth simulation, I eventually get the ghost shape that I want.  Now, I want to add some actions for it.  How do I "pause" it at the ghost shape that I want and start making animations for it, like Idle (I want the cloth to swing around a bit, like the ghost is swinging its hips) and Walk (I want the cloth to flow back like it's walking).  I hope that made sense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I run the cloth simulation, I eventually get the ghost shape that I want.

...

> How do I "pause" it at the ghost shape that I want

## Part 1.

[image: Selected Cloth] Go to the frame you want and make sure the cloth settings are perfect. This change will be permanent. [image: Apply] Go to your modifiers panel and click Apply.
[image: editable mesh] This will convert it from a dynamic modifier into an editable mesh.

> Now, I want to add some actions for it.

...

> I want and start making animations for it, like Idle (I want the cloth to swing around a bit, like the ghost is swinging its hips) and Walk (I want the cloth to flow back like it's walking).

## Part 2.

Next you'll want to rig the ghost. An armature system is a complex topic but I'll give you the basics.

[image: Add bone] Start by adding a bone to your ghost.
[image: xray] Enable X-ray so you can see what you're doing
[image: Edit] Making sure your bone is positioned at the top of the ghost hit `TAB` to go into edit mode and `E` to extrude it down once.
[image: Select "with automatic weights"] Back in object mode select your ghost, hold down `SHIFT` and then select your armature you just created. Press `CTRL` and `P` to bring up the menu in the illustration.
[image: Animation screen] Finally animate the ghost how you like it to look.

Here's a GIF of what I came up with:
[image: Ghost glides across screen] Not bad for simple it was to create. More bones gives you more control obviously.

Comment: Not bad at all.  Thanks so much for all the detail!  I will try this out tomorrow.

Comment: Glad I could help. I tried to make it as easy as I could to follow let me know if there are any questions.

Comment: Is there any way to make the cloth still move like cloth during animation after the cloth modifier has been applied?

Comment: The problem is that Blender cloth sim does not work with the game engine from the little I know. You might try adding more bones for a finer level of control and animating it from there. But like I said I know little about the game engine.

Comment: Just FYI, I re-added a cloth modifier back to the cloth again to make it animate like cloth.  Thanks again.