# Cloth simulation for game engine doesn't get animated despite Shape Keys have been created

Tags: animation, game-engine, cloth-simulation, shape-keys, actions

I’ve been exploring and fighting this problem for a few weeks with no result and I’m really out of ideas.

I have to create a character (to import to Xcode). It is a standing in place ghost with its 'cloth' just waving in a loop (I used wind force). The only element I need to export is a waving cloth. I have prepared the simulation, baked it, exported as .mdd, imported the .mdd to obtain Shape Keys, removed irrelevant elements (incl. cloth modifier) and… I am not able to turn it into animation…

At first I presumed it’s an export problem (I posted [Exporting cloth simulation to Collada results in static cloth instead of a waving one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101297/exporting-cloth-simulation-to-collada-results-in-static-cloth-instead-of-a-wavin/101308?noredirect=1#comment179372_101308) ), but then I realized that it’s not - the object is static and there is no animation.

I have proper Shape Keys but no idea how to push them run as animation. I have tried different methods to link Shape Keys to actions - still I’m not sure whether it is the core problem. I have added armature then run a script to create drivers between Shape Keys and Armature (as in https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?325838-How-to-convert-a-cloth-simulation-animation-to-keyframes and here https://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-261576.html and [How to convert cloth simulation into mesh animation?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42784/how-to-convert-cloth-simulation-into-mesh-animation) ). I manually added an action to the Cloth, but I don’t know whether it was needed. I don’t even know if there has been established any relation between Shape Keys and any action. I have applied Object transform (scale, rotation..) - no result… This [How to export a scene with Shape Keys Animation?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43154/how-to-export-a-scene-with-shape-keys-animation) also doesn't work for me...
This one [Create ghost character from a certain point in cloth simulation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16545/create-ghost-character-from-a-certain-point-in-cloth-simulation) is also not a solution - at the end there is again cloth modified added. I see there are few threads that might be related to mine but they remain unsolved.

Here the pain blend can be downloaded https://files.fm/u/sm2gkvv5

I export Collada and .blend to Unity for testing - there is an animation (I see frames running) but the cloth is static - not deforming.

I guess the solution must be very simple (I am a newbie) or there is a bug… Maybe anyone can help and tell me what is missing? There must be a way to export characters with animated cloth to game engines!…

I’m using Blender 2.79.

[image: trying to get shape keys animated]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Unity is importing the .fbx from the .blend in wrong ways ([Unity imports .blend files as .fbx under the hood](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-ImportObjectBlender.html)).
I downloaded your .blend file, exported **manually** to .fbx and I can see the cloth waving in Unity3D.

I'm using Blender 2.79 and Unity3D 2017.3.0f2.

Try as follows:

1. In **Object mode** select both mesh and armature

[image: Select both mesh and armature in object mode]

2. Select **File** -> **Export** -> **FBX**
3. Disable **Add Leaf Bones**

[image]

4. Import the .fbx file into Unity

[Animations in action](https://gfycat.com/EmptyLawfulFlies)

Comment: This could have been a simple comment but I still can't comment other posts (reputation <50) and I wanted to help the OP. Still I tried to make the answer as complete as possible.

Comment: Hi Cacti! Wow! Thank you for having a look into my issue. It seems that somehow the animation gets exported to .fbx (and it is visible in Unity). Still, exported Collada file doesn't include mesh animation - it should be visible in MacOS Preview and the ghost keeps standing still.

Comment: Cacti, I marked your answer as useful, but it seems it will be visible after I achieve 15 points... Best of luck in your projects!

Answer (score 0):

After so long research I am coming to conclusion that using a cloth sim (and expecting it to run in .dae or alembic .abc) was a mistake that took me to a "dead end"... Fbx - yes, other formats - I don't know. I guess I have to re-design the character or perhaps use different 3D software.

I hope this information will help others to save time.